# turtle onclick() method not working as it should

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The following code creates a window in which a python turtle follows wherever your mouse goes. However, it draws indescriminately of whether the user is clicking to draw or not. My code is the following:

Note: *You must have pythonwin installed in order for this program to work properly*

```
    import turtle, win32api
    while True:
            # turtle.penup()
        user = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        mousepos = [user[0]-510,-1*(user[1])+ 410]
        turtle.goto(mousepos)
        turtle.onclick(turtle.pendown())
```

In theory, this would only draw when the user is pressing and holding the mouse, but it doesn't work in practice. The commented code will simply cause it to not draw at all. Any advice?

Comment: According to the documentation of [turtle.onclick](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html#turtle.onclick) it wants a function with two arguments, you may have to make a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

```
turtle.onclick(turtle.pendown())
```

Here, you are calling `pendown()`, which returns probably None; then you're passing this None to `onclick()`.  It probably means "do nothing on a click".  That's probably not what you want.

According to @Gibby's comment, you want:

```
def clicked(*args):   # args ignored
    turtle.pendown()
turtle.onclick(clicked)
```